# strcmp function in matlab

Tags: matlab, strcmp

Suppose we have the following cell arrays that store the name and gender of subjects who participated in an experiment:

```
Names = { 'Amy' , 'Chris' , 'John' , 'Karin' , 'Juan' };
Gender = { 'Female' , 'Male' , 'Male' , 'Female' , 'Male' };
```

Suppose the experiment also measures response times for a number of trials. We store this information in the following matrix where each column corresponds to a person and each row corresponds to a trial in the experiment:

```
ResponseTimes = [ 2.4 2.2 2.9 2.7 2.7;
                  1.6 1.7 1.9 1.5 1.0;
                  2.1 2.2 0.9 2.5 1.9;
                  1.7 2.4 1.6 2.1 1.4 ];
```

How can I create a Matlab command that lists all male names using the `strcmp` function?

Comment: Are the response times of any relevance to the question?

Answer (score 4):

You can try

```
Names(strcmp(Gender, 'Male'))
```

which results in

```
ans = 
    'Chris'    'John'    'Juan'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, you may also want the corresponding response times:

```
idx = strcmp(Gender, 'Male');
maleNames = Names(idx);
maleResponseTimes = ResponseTimes(:,idx);
```

For females use `Names(~idx)` and `ResponseTimes(:,~idx)`